# Does half-affine imply affine?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ denote real vector spaces, and consider a function $f : V \rightarrow W.$ Bind the variables $x$ and $y$ to $V$.

Call $f$:

- *half-linear* iff for all real $a,b \geq 0,$ we have $f(ax+by) = af(x)+bf(y)$.
- *half-affine* iff for all real $a,b \geq 0$ with $a+b= 1,$ we have $f(ax+by) = af(x)+bf(y)$.

Then trivially, *linear* implies *half-linear* and *affine* implies *half-affine*. In fact, we have a converse: half-linear implies linear (I can supply a proof if anyone is interested). The following question remains:

> **Question.** Does half-affine imply affine?

Comment: As we see below, half-linear as stated is automatically linear. The following variant is interesting: let $f$ be half-linear if for real $a,b \geq 0$ and $x,y$ *linearly independent* $f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$.

Comment: @MikeMiller, that does sound interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. Let $g$ be defined by $g(x)=
f(x)-f(\overrightarrow{0})$. Then $g$ is still
half-affine, and $g(\overrightarrow{0})=\overrightarrow{0}$. We 
deduce $(1) : g(by)=bg(y)$ for any $b\in[0,1]$. Let $b\geq 1$. Replacing 
$(b,y)$ with $(\frac{1}{b},by)$ in (1), we find
$g(y)=\frac{1}{b}g(by)$. We see then that (1) holds for any 
$b\geq 0$.

Let $a,b$ be positive numbers and $x,y\in V$. Suppose $a>0$. We have
$g(ax+by)=(a+b)g(\frac{ax+by}{a+b})$ by (1), but the RHS is equal to
$ag(x)+bg(y)$ since $g$ is half-affine. So $g(ax+by)=ag(x)+bg(y)$, and this
stays true if $a=0$ or $b=0$ :

$$
g(ax+by)=ag(x)+bg(y) \ (a,b\geq 0,x,y\in V) \ \ \ \tag{2}
$$

Taking $a=b=1$ and $x=u-v,y=v$ in (2), we have $g(u)=g(u-v)+g(v)$, i.e.

$$
g(u-v)=g(u)-g(v) \ (u,v\in V) \tag{3}
$$

Combining (2) with (3), it is easy to see that $g$ is linear, so $f$
is affine.

Answer (score 1):

For half-linear:

$$0 = f(0) = f(x + (-x)) = f(x) + f(-x) $$

$$f(ax - by) = a f(x) + b f(-y) = a f(x) - b f(y) $$